# Problem with jsp

Tags: jsp

I have a form (with a few fields)..basically a singup form. and i have the username field which should be chosen to be unique by the user. For this i have to connect to database,check whether such a username exists and then display an appropriate message in the same form. All this must happen when i click the "check Availabilty" button. How should i handle this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it all in one form (not recommended), you can write a single JSP using JSTL `<sql>` tags.

A better approach would be to break the problem up into parts.   Start with a Credential class:

```
package model;

public class Credential
{
    private String username;
    private String password;

    // Add the rest.
}
```

Have a DAO interface that lets you get a Credential out of a database:

```
package persistence;

public interface CredentialDao
{
    List<Credential> find();
    Credential find(String username);
}
```

Write a servlet that fields requests from your JSP with the form, validates and binds the input, uses a CredentialDao to search for the Credential given a username, and then decides what to send as the response to the JSP by examining what comes back.

Answer (score 0):

1. get username
2. check if it exists using "select username from..."
3. if it exists, redirect user to an error page telling them that user already exists (or use Ajax to tell them the same thing on one page)
4. if it doesn't exist, register a new user using "insert username to..." or whatever mechanism you're using and then tell user registration was sucessfull

Comment: how to redirect using ajax? any references?

Comment: @nikhil: you don't have to redirect using Ajax, but simply add to existing page some html that says "an error with this username already exists". How to do this depends on what JS framework you're using. If you're using jQuery, check out its [home page](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: @nikhil: jsp is a Java technology. You need to use Javascript. Google for "xmlhttprequest java" and I'm sure you'll find info you need.